# How to execute last line using getline

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to use getline to read in each line separately from a file, but the last line in the file is not followed by an end of line deliminator so getline does not know that it has reached the end of the line.

I'm using the terminal to execute the program by using ./evaluation < input0 where input0 is the input file and the last line in input0 is read in but isn't executed into the code. Below is what I am trying to do:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) 
{
    //reading in value from user
    while( 1 )
    {
        //starting output
        cout << "Expression: ";

        string expressionInputs;
        string postfix;

        while( getline( cin, expressionInputs ) )
        {
            break;
        }
        cout << expressionInputs << endl;

        //checks to see if Ctrl+d has been used as input
        if( cin.eof() )
        {
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }
        postfix = infixToPostfix( expressionInputs );
        cout << "Answer: " << postfixToAnswer( postfix ) << endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

The program is suppose to read in values such as 1+2 and convert it to postfix ( 1 2 +) and then evaluate the answer.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through the program and see what is happening?

Comment: "but the last line in the file is not followed by an end of line deliminator so getline does not know that it has reached the end of the line" - `std::getline()` is definitely designed to figure that out so I suspect you have a different problem.

Comment: I suspect your real problem is that you never reach the end of file (being that user input never ends [unless you type Ctrl-D]).

Comment: it wold be as if the user never hit enter. The program exits out before evaluating the last line.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will fix your program, but might I suggest putting your call to `getline` as the condition for the outer while loop and taking out the if statement inside (and declaring your strings outside the loop of course).

Comment: say the file contained:

1+2
1*(2+3)
3/(100-3) this line would be read in but it would never get executed. Meaning that it would never be read into infixToPostfix or postfixToAnswer.

Comment: The file can have a '\n' followed by a EOF - This might be indistinguishable in a editor.

Answer (score 0):

You're interpreting the outcome of [`std::basic_ios::operator bool()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) correctly, so I wonder if your last line in the file is empty. In your program, when [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) returns false, that means that it wasn't able to read any characters before encountering either a newline or EOF.

Note that `getline()` is returning `cin` here, and your `while` statement is evaluating `operator bool()` on it. That `operator bool()` will return false if the preceding operation failed, but encountering EOF is not sufficient to count as failure—again, in this case, unless there were no characters available after the preceding line.

Do you have a sample input file that you can share here?